# An algorithm to find bounding box of closed bezier curves?

Tags: algorithm, bezier

I'm looking for an algorithm to find bounding box (max/min points) of a closed quadratic bezier curve in Cartesian axis:

```
input: C (a closed bezier curve)
output: A B C D points
```

[Image http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1270586513022388700.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1270586513022388700.jpg)

**Note**: above image shows a smooth curve. it could be not smooth. (have corners)

Comment: edit that into your question please

Comment: If you know the quadratic equation can you not calculate y values for each x value, noting the lowest and highest y value for the range of x values?

Comment: @ James Westgate : Hmm... it could be difficult to calculate, or even to convert bezier equation to form of y=f(x) for every curve. I'm writing python code to accomplish. so i want an algorithm not a solution.

Comment: @JamesWestgate: If I understand what you mean, then you're only sampling the curve, and your chances of finding the exact bounds are minimal, and their is also a chance of being way off. That would be like trying to find the min of a parabola by checking the y-value for every integer value of x. In reality, you need to "sample" the curve at infinitesimal distances, which is why calculus was invented =). The nice thing about Beziers is that you don't need to find the derivative it's given to you as a set of parametric equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would say you start by adding all endpoints to your bounding box. Then, you go through all the bezier elements. I assume the formula in question is this one:

[image: Quadratic Bezier from Wikipedia]

From this, extract two formulas for X and Y, respectively. Test both for extrema by taking the derivative (zero crossings). Then add the corresponding points to your bounding box as well.

Comment: @ypnos: Thanks. how could i do test of extrema with a programming language? i think this needs a CAS and I don't have one! could introduce free one for python please?

Comment: It's easier to calculate the points where the derivative is zero directly as t0=(P1-P0)/(P0-2P1+P2).

Comment: Well the extrema test in your case is a rather simple formula and the number of solutions is known beforehand. So you will perhaps need one or two if statements, but the rest is just calculation. I don't do Python, sorry.

Comment: At Tom: I think there's a sign error in your formula. It should be t0=(P1-P0)/(-P0+2P1-P2).

Comment: how could one "extract two formulas for X and Y"?

Answer (score 28):

[Ivan Kuckir's DeCasteljau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378980/1691517) is a brute force, but works in many cases. The problem with it is the count of iterations. The actual shape and the distance between coordinates affect to the precision of the result. And to find a precise enough answer, you have to iterate tens of times, may be more. And it may fail if there are sharp turns in curve.

Better solution is to find **first derivative roots**, as is described on the excellent site http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/. Please read the section *Finding the extremities of the curves*.

The link above has the algorithm for both quadratic and cubic curves.

The asker of question is interested in quadratic curves, so the rest of this answer may be irrelevant, because I provide codes for calculating extremities of Cubic curves.

Below are three Javascript codes of which the first (CODE 1) is the one I suggest to use.

---

** CODE 1 **

After testing processingjs and Raphael's solutions I find they had some restrictions and/or bugs. Then more search and found Bonsai and it's [bounding box function](https://github.com/uxebu/bonsai/blob/master/src/runner/path/curved_path.js), which is based on NISHIO Hirokazu's Python script. Both have a downside where double equality is tested using `==`. When I changed these to numerically robust comparisons, then script succeeds 100% right in all cases. I tested the script with thousands of random paths and also with all collinear cases and all succeeded:

[Various cubic curves](https://output.jsbin.com/sigugex/1/)

[Random cubic curves](https://jsfiddle.net/timo2012/fj1akt8e/2/)

[Collinear cubic curves](https://output.jsbin.com/vewagew/1/)

The code is as follows. Usually left, right, top and bottom values are the all needed, but in some cases it's fine to know the coordinates of local extreme points and corresponding t values. So I added there two variables: `tvalues` and `points`. Remove code regarding them and you have fast and stable bounding box calculation function.

```
// Source: http://blog.hackers-cafe.net/2009/06/how-to-calculate-bezier-curves-bounding.html
// Original version: NISHIO Hirokazu
// Modifications: Timo

var pow = Math.pow,
  sqrt = Math.sqrt,
  min = Math.min,
  max = Math.max;
  abs = Math.abs;

function getBoundsOfCurve(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
{
  var tvalues = new Array();
  var bounds = [new Array(), new Array()];
  var points = new Array();

  var a, b, c, t, t1, t2, b2ac, sqrtb2ac;
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      b = 6 * x0 - 12 * x1 + 6 * x2;
      a = -3 * x0 + 9 * x1 - 9 * x2 + 3 * x3;
      c = 3 * x1 - 3 * x0;
    }
    else
    {
      b = 6 * y0 - 12 * y1 + 6 * y2;
      a = -3 * y0 + 9 * y1 - 9 * y2 + 3 * y3;
      c = 3 * y1 - 3 * y0;
    }

    if (abs(a) < 1e-12) // Numerical robustness
    {
      if (abs(b) < 1e-12) // Numerical robustness
      {
        continue;
      }
      t = -c / b;
      if (0 < t && t < 1)
      {
        tvalues.push(t);
      }
      continue;
    }
    b2ac = b * b - 4 * c * a;
    sqrtb2ac = sqrt(b2ac);
    if (b2ac < 0)
    {
      continue;
    }
    t1 = (-b + sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t1 && t1 < 1)
    {
      tvalues.push(t1);
    }
    t2 = (-b - sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t2 && t2 < 1)
    {
      tvalues.push(t2);
    }
  }

  var x, y, j = tvalues.length,
    jlen = j,
    mt;
  while (j--)
  {
    t = tvalues[j];
    mt = 1 - t;
    x = (mt * mt * mt * x0) + (3 * mt * mt * t * x1) + (3 * mt * t * t * x2) + (t * t * t * x3);
    bounds[0][j] = x;

    y = (mt * mt * mt * y0) + (3 * mt * mt * t * y1) + (3 * mt * t * t * y2) + (t * t * t * y3);
    bounds[1][j] = y;
    points[j] = {
      X: x,
      Y: y
    };
  }

  tvalues[jlen] = 0;
  tvalues[jlen + 1] = 1;
  points[jlen] = {
    X: x0,
    Y: y0
  };
  points[jlen + 1] = {
    X: x3,
    Y: y3
  };
  bounds[0][jlen] = x0;
  bounds[1][jlen] = y0;
  bounds[0][jlen + 1] = x3;
  bounds[1][jlen + 1] = y3;
  tvalues.length = bounds[0].length = bounds[1].length = points.length = jlen + 2;

  return {
    left: min.apply(null, bounds[0]),
    top: min.apply(null, bounds[1]),
    right: max.apply(null, bounds[0]),
    bottom: max.apply(null, bounds[1]),
    points: points, // local extremes
    tvalues: tvalues // t values of local extremes
  };
};

// Usage:
var bounds = getBoundsOfCurve(532,333,117,305,28,93,265,42);
console.log(JSON.stringify(bounds));
// Prints: {"left":135.77684049079755,"top":42,"right":532,"bottom":333,"points":[{"X":135.77684049079755,"Y":144.86387466397255},{"X":532,"Y":333},{"X":265,"Y":42}],"tvalues":[0.6365030674846626,0,1]}
```

---

**CODE 2 (which fails in collinear cases):**

I translated the code from http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/sketchsource.php?sketch=tightBoundsCubicBezier to Javascript. The code works fine in normal cases, but not in collinear cases where all points lie on the same line.

For reference, here is the Javascript code.

```
function computeCubicBaseValue(a,b,c,d,t) {
    var mt = 1-t;
    return mt*mt*mt*a + 3*mt*mt*t*b + 3*mt*t*t*c + t*t*t*d; 
}

function computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(a,b,c,d) {
    var ret = [-1,-1];
  var tl = -a+2*b-c;
  var tr = -Math.sqrt(-a*(c-d) + b*b - b*(c+d) +c*c);
  var dn = -a+3*b-3*c+d;
    if(dn!=0) { ret[0] = (tl+tr)/dn; ret[1] = (tl-tr)/dn; }
    return ret; 
}

function computeCubicBoundingBox(xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc,xd,yd)
{
    // find the zero point for x and y in the derivatives
  var minx = 9999;
  var maxx = -9999;
    if(xa<minx) { minx=xa; }
    if(xa>maxx) { maxx=xa; }
    if(xd<minx) { minx=xd; }
    if(xd>maxx) { maxx=xd; }
    var ts = computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(xa, xb, xc, xd);
    for(var i=0; i<ts.length;i++) {
      var t = ts[i];
        if(t>=0 && t<=1) {
          var x = computeCubicBaseValue(t, xa, xb, xc, xd);
          var y = computeCubicBaseValue(t, ya, yb, yc, yd);
            if(x<minx) { minx=x; }
            if(x>maxx) { maxx=x; }}}

  var miny = 9999;
  var maxy = -9999;
    if(ya<miny) { miny=ya; }
    if(ya>maxy) { maxy=ya; }
    if(yd<miny) { miny=yd; }
    if(yd>maxy) { maxy=yd; }
    ts = computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(ya, yb, yc, yd);
    for(i=0; i<ts.length;i++) {
      var t = ts[i];
        if(t>=0 && t<=1) {
          var x = computeCubicBaseValue(t, xa, xb, xc, xd);
          var y = computeCubicBaseValue(t, ya, yb, yc, yd);
            if(y<miny) { miny=y; }
            if(y>maxy) { maxy=y; }}}

    // bounding box corner coordinates
    var bbox = [minx,miny, maxx,miny, maxx,maxy, minx,maxy ];
    return bbox;
}
```

---

**CODE 3 (works in most cases):**

To handle also collinear cases, I found Raphael's solution, which is based on the same first derivative method as the CODE 2. I added also a return value `dots`, which has the extrema points, because always it's not enough to know bounding boxes min and max coordinates, but we want to know the exact extrema coordinates.

EDIT: found another bug. Fails eg. in 532,333,117,305,28,93,265,42 and also many other cases.

The code is here:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
  return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
Array.min = function( array ){
  return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};

var findDotAtSegment = function (p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y, t) {
        var t1 = 1 - t;
        return {
            x: t1*t1*t1*p1x + t1*t1*3*t*c1x + t1*3*t*t * c2x + t*t*t * p2x,
            y: t1*t1*t1*p1y + t1*t1*3*t*c1y + t1*3*t*t * c2y + t*t*t * p2y
        };
};
var cubicBBox = function (p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y) {
        var a = (c2x - 2 * c1x + p1x) - (p2x - 2 * c2x + c1x),
            b = 2 * (c1x - p1x) - 2 * (c2x - c1x),
            c = p1x - c1x,
            t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a,
            t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a,
            y = [p1y, p2y],
            x = [p1x, p2x],
            dot, dots=[];
        Math.abs(t1) > "1e12" && (t1 = 0.5);
        Math.abs(t2) > "1e12" && (t2 = 0.5);
        if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1) {
            dot = findDotAtSegment(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y, t1);
            x.push(dot.x);
            y.push(dot.y);
            dots.push({X:dot.x, Y:dot.y});
        }
        if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1) {
            dot = findDotAtSegment(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y, t2);
            x.push(dot.x);
            y.push(dot.y);
            dots.push({X:dot.x, Y:dot.y});
        }
        a = (c2y - 2 * c1y + p1y) - (p2y - 2 * c2y + c1y);
        b = 2 * (c1y - p1y) - 2 * (c2y - c1y);
        c = p1y - c1y;
        t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a;
        t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a;
        Math.abs(t1) > "1e12" && (t1 = 0.5);
        Math.abs(t2) > "1e12" && (t2 = 0.5);
        if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1) {
            dot = findDotAtSegment(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y, t1);
            x.push(dot.x);
            y.push(dot.y);
            dots.push({X:dot.x, Y:dot.y});
        }
        if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1) {
            dot = findDotAtSegment(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y, t2);
            x.push(dot.x);
            y.push(dot.y);
            dots.push({X:dot.x, Y:dot.y});
        }
        // remove duplicate dots
                var dots2 = [];
                var l = dots.length;
                for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
                  for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
                    if (dots[i].X === dots[j].X && dots[i].Y === dots[j].Y)
                      j = ++i;
                  }
                  dots2.push({X: dots[i].X, Y: dots[i].Y});
                }
        return {
        min: {x: Array.min(x), y: Array.min(y)},
        max: {x: Array.max(x), y: Array.max(y)},
        dots: dots2 // these are the extrema points
      };
    };
```

Comment: If you move that `if (b2ac < 0)` check one line up, you prevent attempting to take a square root of a negative number. This doesn't hurt in JS, but makes porting easier.

Comment: Awesome work! I used CODE 3 in [this Khan Academy code snippet](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/beziervertex-drawing-tool-with-aabb-computation/4773474588), and it works out of the box!

Comment: @Domi CODE 3 fails in many cases. See an example here: http://output.jsbin.com/vebavesivu/1 . Blue rectange is the right bbox, red is CODE 3 bbox. I suggest to use the blue rectangle code (CODE 1).

Comment: @Timo Thanks! I skimmed over too much of the explanation apparently! :)

Comment: wasn't the question about quadratic, not cubic curves?

Answer (score 7):

Use De Casteljau algorithm to approximate the curve of higher orders. Here is how it works for cubic curve
http://jsfiddle.net/4VCVX/25/

```
function getCurveBounds(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy)
{
        var px, py, qx, qy, rx, ry, sx, sy, tx, ty,
            tobx, toby, tocx, tocy, todx, tody, toqx, toqy, 
            torx, tory, totx, toty;
        var x, y, minx, miny, maxx, maxy;

        minx = miny = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        maxx = maxy = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

        tobx = bx - ax;  toby = by - ay;  // directions
        tocx = cx - bx;  tocy = cy - by;
        todx = dx - cx;  tody = dy - cy;
        var step = 1/40;      // precision
        for(var d=0; d<1.001; d+=step)
        {
            px = ax +d*tobx;  py = ay +d*toby;
            qx = bx +d*tocx;  qy = by +d*tocy;
            rx = cx +d*todx;  ry = cy +d*tody;
            toqx = qx - px;      toqy = qy - py;
            torx = rx - qx;      tory = ry - qy;

            sx = px +d*toqx;  sy = py +d*toqy;
            tx = qx +d*torx;  ty = qy +d*tory;
            totx = tx - sx;   toty = ty - sy;

            x = sx + d*totx;  y = sy + d*toty;                
            minx = Math.min(minx, x); miny = Math.min(miny, y);
            maxx = Math.max(maxx, x); maxy = Math.max(maxy, y);
        }        
        return {x:minx, y:miny, width:maxx-minx, height:maxy-miny};
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of the four vertices? Which are the anchor and which are the control point?

Comment: Sure, A (=[ax,ay]) is the start point, D is the end point. B is the control point related to A, C is the control point related to D.

Comment: Might want to fix the naming :)

Comment: Bézeir curves are usually defined by the sequence of N points, the first point is the beginning, the last point is the end and points in between control the shape.

Comment: I love that the comment "precission" is misspelled. Very precise.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the control points of a Bezier curve form a convex hull that encloses the curve.  If you just want a axis-aligned bounding box, I think you need to find the min and max of each (x, y) for each control point of all the segments.

I suppose that might not be a *tight* box.  That is, the box might be slightly larger than it needs to be, but it's simple and fast to compute.  I guess it depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: Thanks for answer. but I need to find a rectangle with minimum area.

Comment: @drawnonward:  [Wikipedia says][1]: "the curve is completely contained in the convex hull of its control points"

  [1]:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: "The curve can be outside the bounds of the control points" is true, if we consider only the off curve control points. If also start and end point are considered as control points, then the sentence is not true.

Comment: @Timo: Can you clarify?  The start and end points of a Bezier curve belong to the set of control points.  You must include them as well as the other control points in order to form a convex hull.

Comment: I mean that @drawnonward's comment is dangerous, because it assumes that start and end point are not control points. Usually they are considered as control points and then the sentence is not true.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy +1 for the sound, sensible advice; it wouldn't be a tight box, but would be more performant and simple to use all four points (of a cubic bezier curve) to form its bounding box.

Answer (score 5):

I think the accepted answer is fine, but just wanted to offer a little more explanation for anyone else trying to do this.

Consider a quadratic Bezier with starting point `p1`, ending point `p2` and "control point" `pc`. This curve has three parametric equations:

1. `pa(t) = p1 + t(pc-p1)`
2. `pb(t) = pc + t(p2-pc)`
3. `p(t) = pa(t) + t*(pb(t) - pa(t))`

In all cases, `t` runs from 0 to 1, inclusive.

The first two are linear, defining line segments from `p1` to `pc` and from `pc` to `p2`, respectively. The third is quadratic once you substitute in the expressions for `pa(t)` and `pb(t)`; this is the one that actually defines points on the curve.

Actually, each of these equations is a pair of equations, one for the horizontal dimension, and one for the vertical. The nice thing about parametric curves is that the x and y can be handled independently of one another. The equations are exactly the same, just substitute `x` or `y` for `p` in the above equations.

The important point is that the line segment defined in equation 3, that runs from `pa(t)` to `pb(t)` for a specific value of `t` is *tangent* to the curve at the corresponding point `p(t)`. To find the local extrema of the curve, you need to find the parameter value where the tangent is flat (i.e., a critical point). For the vertical dimension, you want to find the value of `t` such that `ya(t) = yb(t)`, which gives the tangent a slope of 0. For the horizontal dimension, find `t` such that `xa(t) = xb(t)`, which gives the tangent an infinite slope (i.e., a vertical line). In each case, you can just plug the value of t back into equation 1 (or 2, or even 3) to get the location of that extrema.

In other words, to find the vertical extrema of the curve, take just the y-component of equations 1 and 2, set them equal to each other and solve for `t`; plug this back into the y-component of equation 1, to get the y-value of that extrema. To get the complete y-range of the curve, find the minimum of this extreme y value and the y-components of the two end points, and likewise find the maximum of all three. Repeat for x to get the horizontal limits.

Remember that `t` only runs in [0, 1], so if you get a value outside of this range, it means there is no local extrema on the curve (at least not between your two endpoints). This includes the case where you end up dividing by zero when solving for `t`, which you will probably need to check for before you do it.

The same idea can be applied to higher-order Beziers, there are just more equations of higher degree, which also means there are potentially more local extrema per curve. For instance, on a cubic Bezier (two control points), solving for `t` to find the local extrema is a quadratic equation, so you could get 0, 1, or 2 values (remember to check for 0-denominators, and for negative square-roots, both of which indicate that there are no local extrema for that dimension). To find the range, you just need to find the min/max of all the local extrema, and the two end points.

Answer (score 3):

I answered this question in [Calculating the bounding box of cubic bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809978/calculating-the-bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier-curve)

this article explain the details and also has a live html5 demo:
[Calculating / Computing the Bounding Box of Cubic Bezier](http://floris.briolas.nl/floris/2009/10/bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier/)

I found a javascript in Snap.svg to calculate that: [here](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/path.js#L180)
see the bezierBBox and curveDim functions.

I rewrite a javascript function.

```js
    //(x0,y0) is start point; (x1,y1),(x2,y2) is control points; (x3,y3) is end point.
    function bezierMinMax(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
        var tvalues = [], xvalues = [], yvalues = [],
            a, b, c, t, t1, t2, b2ac, sqrtb2ac;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                b = 6 * x0 - 12 * x1 + 6 * x2;
                a = -3 * x0 + 9 * x1 - 9 * x2 + 3 * x3;
                c = 3 * x1 - 3 * x0;
            } else {
                b = 6 * y0 - 12 * y1 + 6 * y2;
                a = -3 * y0 + 9 * y1 - 9 * y2 + 3 * y3;
                c = 3 * y1 - 3 * y0;
            }
            if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-12) {
                if (Math.abs(b) < 1e-12) {
                    continue;
                }
                t = -c / b;
                if (0 < t && t < 1) {
                    tvalues.push(t);
                }
                continue;
            }
            b2ac = b * b - 4 * c * a;
            if (b2ac < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            sqrtb2ac = Math.sqrt(b2ac);
            t1 = (-b + sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);
            if (0 < t1 && t1 < 1) {
                tvalues.push(t1);
            }
            t2 = (-b - sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);
            if (0 < t2 && t2 < 1) {
                tvalues.push(t2);
            }
        }
    
        var j = tvalues.length, mt;
        while (j--) {
            t = tvalues[j];
            mt = 1 - t;
            xvalues[j] = (mt * mt * mt * x0) + (3 * mt * mt * t * x1) + (3 * mt * t * t * x2) + (t * t * t * x3);
            yvalues[j] = (mt * mt * mt * y0) + (3 * mt * mt * t * y1) + (3 * mt * t * t * y2) + (t * t * t * y3);
        }
    
        xvalues.push(x0,x3);
        yvalues.push(y0,y3);
    
        return {
            min: {x: Math.min.apply(0, xvalues), y: Math.min.apply(0, yvalues)},
            max: {x: Math.max.apply(0, xvalues), y: Math.max.apply(0, yvalues)}
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Timo-s first variant adapted to Objective-C

```
CGPoint CubicBezierPointAt(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3, CGPoint p4, CGFloat t) {

   CGFloat x = CubicBezier(p1.x, p2.x, p3.x, p4.x, t);
   CGFloat y = CubicBezier(p1.y, p2.y, p3.y, p4.y, t);

   return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

// array containing TopLeft and BottomRight points for curve`s enclosing bounds
NSArray* CubicBezierExtremums(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3, CGPoint p4) {

   CGFloat a, b, c, t, t1, t2, b2ac, sqrtb2ac;
   NSMutableArray *tValues = [NSMutableArray new];

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
         a = 3 * (-p1.x + 3 * p2.x - 3 * p3.x + p4.x);
         b = 6 * (p1.x - 2 * p2.x +  p3.x);
         c = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x);
      }
      else {
         a = 3 * (-p1.y + 3 * p2.y - 3 * p3.y + p4.y);
         b = 6 * (p1.y - 2 * p2.y +  p3.y);
         c = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y);
      }

      if(ABS(a) < CGFLOAT_MIN) {// Numerical robustness
         if (ABS(b) < CGFLOAT_MIN) {// Numerical robustness
            continue;
         }

         t = -c / b;

         if (t > 0 && t < 1) {
            [tValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t]];
         }
         continue;
      }

      b2ac = pow(b, 2) - 4 * c * a;

      if (b2ac < 0) {
         continue;
      }

      sqrtb2ac = sqrt(b2ac);

      t1 = (-b + sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);

      if (t1 > 0.0 && t1 < 1.0) {
         [tValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t1]];
      }

      t2 = (-b - sqrtb2ac) / (2 * a);

      if (t2 > 0.0 && t2 < 1.0) {
         [tValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t2]];
      }
   }

   int j = (int)tValues.count;

   CGFloat x = 0;
   CGFloat y = 0;
   NSMutableArray *xValues = [NSMutableArray new];
   NSMutableArray *yValues = [NSMutableArray new];

   while (j--) {
      t = [[tValues objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue];
      x = CubicBezier(p1.x, p2.x, p3.x, p4.x, t);
      y = CubicBezier(p1.y, p2.y, p3.y, p4.y, t);
      [xValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:x]];
      [yValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:y]];
   }

   [xValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p1.x]];
   [xValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p4.x]];
   [yValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p1.y]];
   [yValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p4.y]];

   //find minX, minY, maxX, maxY
   CGFloat minX = [[xValues valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue];
   CGFloat minY = [[yValues valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue];
   CGFloat maxX = [[xValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] doubleValue];
   CGFloat maxY = [[yValues valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] doubleValue];

   CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(minX, minY);
   CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(maxX, maxY);

   NSArray *toReturn = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:origin],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:bottomRight],
                        nil];

   return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: The `CubicBezier` function is undefined here 

Answer (score 0):

[Timo's CODE 2 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429749/935476) has a small bug: the `t` parameter in `computeCubicBaseValue` function should be last.  Nevertheless good job, works like a charm ;)

Solution in C# :

```cs
double computeCubicBaseValue(double a, double b, double c, double d, double t)
{
    var mt = 1 - t;
    return mt * mt * mt * a + 3 * mt * mt * t * b + 3 * mt * t * t * c + t * t * t * d;
}

double[] computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    var ret = new double[2] { -1, -1 };
    var tl = -a + 2 * b - c;
    var tr = -Math.Sqrt(-a * (c - d) + b * b - b * (c + d) + c * c);
    var dn = -a + 3 * b - 3 * c + d;
    if (dn != 0) { ret[0] = (tl + tr) / dn; ret[1] = (tl - tr) / dn; }
    return ret;
}

public double[] ComputeCubicBoundingBox(Point start, Point firstControl, Point secondControl, Point end)
{
    double xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, xd, yd;
    xa = start.X;
    ya = start.Y;
    xb = firstControl.X;
    yb = firstControl.Y;
    xc = secondControl.X;
    yc = secondControl.Y;
    xd = end.X;
    yd = end.Y;
    // find the zero point for x and y in the derivatives
    double minx = Double.MaxValue;
    double maxx = Double.MinValue;
    if (xa < minx) { minx = xa; }
    if (xa > maxx) { maxx = xa; }
    if (xd < minx) { minx = xd; }
    if (xd > maxx) { maxx = xd; }
    var ts = computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(xa, xb, xc, xd);
    for (var i = 0; i < ts.Length; i++)
    {
        var t = ts[i];
        if (t >= 0 && t <= 1)
        {
            var x = computeCubicBaseValue(xa, xb, xc, xd,t);
            var y = computeCubicBaseValue(ya, yb, yc, yd,t);
            if (x < minx) { minx = x; }
            if (x > maxx) { maxx = x; }
        }
    }

    double miny = Double.MaxValue;
    double maxy = Double.MinValue;
    if (ya < miny) { miny = ya; }
    if (ya > maxy) { maxy = ya; }
    if (yd < miny) { miny = yd; }
    if (yd > maxy) { maxy = yd; }
    ts = computeCubicFirstDerivativeRoots(ya, yb, yc, yd);
    for (var i = 0; i < ts.Length; i++)
    {
        var t = ts[i];
        if (t >= 0 && t <= 1)
        {
            var x = computeCubicBaseValue(xa, xb, xc, xd,t);
            var y = computeCubicBaseValue(ya, yb, yc, yd,t);
            if (y < miny) { miny = y; }
            if (y > maxy) { maxy = y; }
        }
    }

    // bounding box corner coordinates
    var bbox = new double[] { minx, miny, maxx, maxy};
    return bbox;
}
```