# Get bounding box of SVG path

Tags: svg, intersection, codepen

I want exactly what this page do

http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/vNoemp/

I have the path and need to know it's bounding box as a rect element, it's x,y,width and height 
given code

```
<path d="M147.5 55.8c-5.8-7.2-13.6-14.4-25.5-14.4-8.4 0-15.4 8.2-27 8.2-9 0-13-7.8-23-7.8C51.4 41.8 31 60.4 31 84.5c0 12.8 4.2 32.5 13.6 49.7C51 146.7 59.4 155 69 155c6.7 0 14.7-6.3 24.2-6.3 8.4 0 16.2 5.6 23.8 5.6 18 0 35-23.5 35-39.3 0-.8-.3-1.4-.3-2v-1c-11.8-6.3-18.2-15.7-18.2-29.3 0-11 4.8-20.5 13.6-26.7l.5-.2zm-53-8.8c13.7-4.2 26.3-14.4 26.3-32 0-1.5-.2-3.3-.4-5.3l-.2-.8C106.4 12.6 94 23.4 94 40.3c0 1.6.2 3.6.6 5.8v.8z" style="translate(0px,-212.47488403320312px) scale(1,1)" >
```

and know the rect properties

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With pure JavaScript: give your path an ID and get its bounding box using `getBBox()`.

```
var myPathBox = document.getElementById("myPath").getBBox();
console.log(myPathBox);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var myPathBox = document.getElementById("myPath").getBBox();
console.log(myPathBox);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
 <path id="myPath" d="M147.5 55.8c-5.8-7.2-13.6-14.4-25.5-14.4-8.4 0-15.4 8.2-27 8.2-9 0-13-7.8-23-7.8C51.4 41.8 31 60.4 31 84.5c0 12.8 4.2 32.5 13.6 49.7C51 146.7 59.4 155 69 155c6.7 0 14.7-6.3 24.2-6.3 8.4 0 16.2 5.6 23.8 5.6 18 0 35-23.5 35-39.3 0-.8-.3-1.4-.3-2v-1c-11.8-6.3-18.2-15.7-18.2-29.3 0-11 4.8-20.5 13.6-26.7l.5-.2zm-53-8.8c13.7-4.2 26.3-14.4 26.3-32 0-1.5-.2-3.3-.4-5.3l-.2-.8C106.4 12.6 94 23.4 94 40.3c0 1.6.2 3.6.6 5.8v.8z" style="translate(0px,-212.47488403320312px) scale(1,1)" >
 </svg>
```

Comment: @Gerado can I get x1,y1 and x2,y2 , not x,y,width,heigh?

Comment: @rafatmansour x2 is simply `x1 + width`, and y2 is `y1 + height`. Also, have a look at `getBoundingClientRect()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @Gerado but that if I assume that it will draw horizontal with no rotations ,but I need exactly x2,y2 which specified the end point

Comment: @rafatmansour both functions already compute the `transform`, if any.

Answer (score 2):

#### `getBBox()` requires elements to be appended to the DOM

Besides, elements can't be hidden via CSS `display:none`.

If you need to calculate a bounding box without rendering an element you may create and append a hidden temporary element without introducing layout shifts like so:

```js
  let d = `
        M3,7 
        L13,7 
        m-10,10 
        l10,0 
        V27 
        H23 
        v10 
        h10
        C 33,43 38,47 43,47 
        c 0,5 5,10 10,10
        S 63,67 63,67       
        s -10,10 10,10
        Q 50,50 73,57
        q 20,-5 0,-10
        T 70,40
        t 0,-15
        A 5, 10 45 1 0 40,20  
        a5,5 20 0 1 -10,-10
        Z 
  `;
  
  let bb = getBBFromDHidden(d);
  console.log(bb)
  
  function getBBFromDHidden(d){
    // create temporary and hidden svg
    let ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    let svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg')
    let path = document.createElementNS(ns, 'path')
    svg.setAttribute('style', 'width:0!important; height:0!important; position:fixed!important; overflow:hidden!important; visibility:hidden!important; opacity:0!important' )
    path.setAttribute('d', d)
    svg.append(path)
    document.body.append(svg);
    let bb = path.getBBox()
    
    //remove temporary svg
    svg.remove();
    return bb;
  }
```

#### Calculate bbox from raw pathdata

In case you can't use the natively supported `getBBox()` method e.g. because you're working in a virtual DOM environment you may also calculate a bounding box based on a raw pathdata `d` string.

**Requirements**

1. you need a path data parser converting the `d` pathdata attribute string to an array of calculable command values. I'm using a standalone parser based on the w3c working draft for the [SVGPathData interface](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData) methodology but you could also use Jarek Foksa's [getPathData polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill?tab=readme-ov-file).
2. convert these commands to all absolute and "longhand" commands (shorthand/reflected commands like `h` , `v`, `s`, `t` need to be normalized to their longhand equivalents)
3. Calculate `t` values for extreme points in quadratic and cubic bézier commands – then calculate the actual point coordinates at these `t` values. See also cuixiping's answer ["Calculating the bounding box of cubic bezier curve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809978/calculating-the-bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier-curve#34882840)
4. Calculate x/y extreme points for `A` arc commands – requires a parametrization of the arc command values (rx, ry, angle, largearc, sweep, finalX, finalY) - based on this post ["How do you calculate the axis-aligned bounding box of an ellipse?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87734/how-do-you-calculate-the-axis-aligned-bounding-box-of-an-ellipse/75031511#75031511)

So basically we're combining these non-iterative methods to calculate extremes:

- quadratic béziers – `quadraticBezierExtremeT()`
- cubic béziers – `cubicBezierExtremeT()`
- arcs – `getArcExtemes()`

For movetos, linetos and flat curves we also include each command's final on-path point to get the min/max x and y coordinates of the path.

```js
// wrapper function to calculate boundaries for aeach segment type
function getPathBBox(pathData) {
  let M = {
    x: pathData[0].values[0],
    y: pathData[0].values[1]
  }
  let xArr = [M.x];
  let yArr = [M.y];
  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i]
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let comPrev = pathData[i - 1]
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;

    if (valuesL) {
      let p0 = {
        x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
        y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
      };
      let p = {
        x: values[valuesL - 2],
        y: values[valuesL - 1]
      };

      // add final on path point
      xArr.push(p.x)
      yArr.push(p.y)

      if (type === 'C' || type === 'Q') {
        let cp1 = {
          x: values[0],
          y: values[1]
        };
        let cp2 = type === 'C' ? {
          x: values[2],
          y: values[3]
        } : cp1;
        let pts = type === 'C' ? [p0, cp1, cp2, p] : [p0, cp1, p];

        let bezierExtremesT = getBezierExtremeT(pts)
        bezierExtremesT.forEach(t => {
          let pt = getPointAtBezierT(pts, t);
          xArr.push(pt.x);
          yArr.push(pt.y);
        })
      } else if (type === 'A') {
        let arcExtremes = getArcExtemes(p0, values)
        arcExtremes.forEach(pt => {
          xArr.push(pt.x);
          yArr.push(pt.y);
        })
      }
    }
  }

  let xMin = Math.min(...xArr)
  let xMax = Math.max(...xArr)
  let yMin = Math.min(...yArr)
  let yMax = Math.max(...yArr)
  let bbox = {
    x: xMin,
    y: yMin,
    width: xMax - xMin,
    height: yMax - yMin
  }
  return bbox
}

// wrapper functions for quadratic or cubic bezier point calculation
function getPointAtBezierT(pts, t) {
  let pt = pts.length === 4 ? getPointAtCubicSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3], t) : getPointAtQuadraticSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], t)
  return pt
}


function getBezierExtremeT(pts) {
  let tArr = pts.length === 4 ? cubicBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]) : quadraticBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2]);
  return tArr;
}


/**
 * based on Nikos M.'s answer
 * how-do-you-calculate-the-axis-aligned-bounding-box-of-an-ellipse
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87734/#75031511
 */

function getArcExtemes(p0, values) {
  // compute point on ellipse from angle around ellipse (theta)
  const arc = (theta, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha) => {
    // theta is angle in radians around arc
    // alpha is angle of rotation of ellipse in radians
    var cos = Math.cos(alpha),
      sin = Math.sin(alpha),
      x = rx * Math.cos(theta),
      y = ry * Math.sin(theta);

    return {
      x: cx + cos * x - sin * y,
      y: cy + sin * x + cos * y
    };
  }


  //parametrize arcto data
  let arcData = svgArcToCenterParam(p0.x, p0.y, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6]);
  let {
    rx,
    ry,
    pt,
    endAngle,
    deltaAngle
  } = arcData;

  // arc rotation
  let deg = values[2];

  // final on path point
  let p = {
    x: values[5],
    y: values[6]
  }

  // circle/elipse center coordinates
  let [cx, cy] = [pt.x, pt.y];

  // collect extreme points – add end point
  let extremes = [p]

  // rotation to radians
  let alpha = deg * Math.PI / 180;
  let tan = Math.tan(alpha),
    p1, p2, p3, p4, theta;

  // find min/max from zeroes of directional derivative along x and y
  // along x axis
  theta = Math.atan2(-ry * tan, rx);

  let angle1 = theta;
  let angle2 = theta + Math.PI;
  let angle3 = Math.atan2(ry, rx * tan);
  let angle4 = angle3 + Math.PI;


  // get point for this theta
  p1 = arc(angle1, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);

  // get anti-symmetric point
  p2 = arc(angle2, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);

  // get point for this theta
  p3 = arc(angle3, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);

  // get anti-symmetric point
  p4 = arc(angle4, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);


  // inner bounding box
  let xArr = [p0.x, p.x]
  let yArr = [p0.y, p.y]
  let xMin = Math.min(...xArr)
  let xMax = Math.max(...xArr)
  let yMin = Math.min(...yArr)
  let yMax = Math.max(...yArr)


  // on path point close after start
  let angleAfterStart = endAngle - deltaAngle * 0.001
  let pP2 = arc(angleAfterStart, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);

  // on path point close before end
  let angleBeforeEnd = endAngle - deltaAngle * 0.999
  let pP3 = arc(angleBeforeEnd, cx, cy, rx, ry, alpha);


  /**
   * expected extremes
   * if leaving inner bounding box
   * (between segment start and end point)
   * otherwise exclude elliptic extreme points
   */

  // left
  if (pP2.x < xMin || pP3.x < xMin) {
    extremes.push(p2)
  }

  // top
  if (pP2.y < yMin || pP3.y < yMin) {
    extremes.push(p4)
  }

  // right
  if (pP2.x > xMax || pP3.x > xMax) {
    extremes.push(p1)
  }

  // bottom
  if (pP2.y > yMax || pP3.y > yMax) {
    extremes.push(p3)
  }

  return extremes;
}


// wrapper functions for quadratic or cubic bezier point calculation
function getPointAtBezierT(pts, t) {
  let pt = pts.length === 4 ? getPointAtCubicSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3], t) : getPointAtQuadraticSegmentT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], t)
  return pt
}

function getBezierExtremeT(pts) {
  let tArr = pts.length === 4 ? cubicBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]) : quadraticBezierExtremeT(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2]);
  return tArr;
}


// cubic bezier
function cubicBezierExtremeT(p0, cp1, cp2, p) {
  let [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] = [p0.x, p0.y, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p.x, p.y];
  let extemeT = [],
    a, b, c, t, t1, t2, b2ac, sqrt_b2ac;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      b = 6 * x0 - 12 * x1 + 6 * x2;
      a = -3 * x0 + 9 * x1 - 9 * x2 + 3 * x3;
      c = 3 * x1 - 3 * x0;
    } else {
      b = 6 * y0 - 12 * y1 + 6 * y2;
      a = -3 * y0 + 9 * y1 - 9 * y2 + 3 * y3;
      c = 3 * y1 - 3 * y0;
    }
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-12) {
      if (Math.abs(b) < 1e-12) {
        continue;
      }
      t = -c / b;
      if (0 < t && t < 1) {
        extemeT.push(t);
      }
      continue;
    }
    b2ac = b * b - 4 * c * a;
    if (b2ac < 0) {
      if (Math.abs(b2ac) < 1e-12) {
        t = -b / (2 * a);
        if (0 < t && t < 1) {
          extemeT.push(t);
        }
      }
      continue;
    }
    sqrt_b2ac = Math.sqrt(b2ac);
    t1 = (-b + sqrt_b2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t1 && t1 < 1) {
      extemeT.push(t1);
    }
    t2 = (-b - sqrt_b2ac) / (2 * a);
    if (0 < t2 && t2 < 1) {
      extemeT.push(t2);
    }
  }

  var j = extemeT.length;
  while (j--) {
    t = extemeT[j];
  }
  return extemeT;

}

// quadratic bezier.
function quadraticBezierExtremeT(p0, cp1, p) {
  let [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2] = [p0.x, p0.y, cp1.x, cp1.y, p.x, p.y];
  let extemeT = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    a = i == 0 ? x0 - 2 * x1 + x2 : y0 - 2 * y1 + y2;
    b = i == 0 ? -2 * x0 + 2 * x1 : -2 * y0 + 2 * y1;
    c = i == 0 ? x0 : y0;
    if (Math.abs(a) > 1e-12) {
      t = -b / (2 * a);
      if (t > 0 && t < 1) {
        extemeT.push(t);
      }
    }
  }
  return extemeT
}


/**
 * parse pathData from d attribute
 * the core function to parse the pathData array from a d string
 **/
function parseDtoPathData(d) {
  let dClean = d
    // remove new lines and tabs
    .replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "")
    // replace comma with space
    .replace(/,/g, " ")
    // add space before minus sign
    .replace(/(\d+)(\-)/g, "$1 $2")
    // decompose multiple adjacent decimal delimiters like 0.5.5.5 => 0.5 0.5 0.5
    .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ")
    // add new lines before valid command letters
    .replace(/([mlcsqtahvz])/gi, "\n$1 ")
    // remove duplicate whitespace
    .replace(/\ {2,}/g, " ")
    // remove whitespace from right and left
    .trim();

  // split commands
  let commands = dClean.split("\n").map((val) => {
    return val.trim();
  });

  // compile pathData
  let pathData = [];
  let comLengths = {
    m: 2,
    a: 7,
    c: 6,
    h: 1,
    l: 2,
    q: 4,
    s: 4,
    t: 2,
    v: 1,
    z: 0
  };
  let errors = [];

  // normalize convatenated larceArc and sweep flags
  const unravelArcValues = (values) => {
    let chunksize = 7,
      n = 0,
      arcComs = []
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      let com = values[i]

      // reset counter
      if (n >= chunksize) {
        n = 0
      }
      // if 3. or 4. parameter longer than 1
      if ((n === 3 || n === 4) && com.length > 1) {

        let largeArc = n === 3 ? com.substring(0, 1) : ''
        let sweep = n === 3 ? com.substring(1, 2) : com.substring(0, 1)
        let finalX = n === 3 ? com.substring(2) : com.substring(1)
        let comN = [largeArc, sweep, finalX].filter(Boolean)
        arcComs.push(comN)
        n += comN.length

      } else {
        // regular
        arcComs.push(com)
        n++
      }
    }
    return arcComs.flat().filter(Boolean);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    let com = commands[i].split(" ");
    let type = com.shift();
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let isRel = type === typeRel;

    /**
     * large arc and sweep flags
     * are boolean and can be concatenated like
     * 11 or 01
     * or be concatenated with the final on path points like
     * 1110 10 => 1 1 10 10
     */
    if (typeRel === "a") {
      com = unravelArcValues(com)
    }

    // convert to numbers
    let values = com.map((val) => {
      return parseFloat(val);
    });

    // if string contains repeated shorthand commands - split them
    let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];
    let chunk = values.slice(0, chunkSize);
    pathData.push({
      type: type,
      values: chunk
    });

    // too few values
    if (chunk.length < chunkSize) {
      errors.push(
        `${i}. command (${type}) has ${chunk.length}/${chunkSize} values - ${chunkSize - chunk.length} too few`
      );
    }

    // has implicit commands
    if (values.length > chunkSize) {
      let typeImplicit = typeRel === "m" ? (isRel ? "l" : "L") : type;
      for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize) {
        let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
        pathData.push({
          type: typeImplicit,
          values: chunk
        });
        if (chunk.length !== chunkSize) {
          errors.push(
            `${i}. command (${type}) has ${chunk.length + chunkSize}/${chunkSize} - ${chunk.length} values too many `
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (errors.length) {
    console.log(errors);
  }

  /**
   * first M is always absolute/uppercase -
   * unless it adds relative linetos
   * (facilitates d concatenating)
   */
  pathData[0].type = 'M'
  return pathData;
}


/**
 * converts all commands to absolute
 */

function pathDataToLonghands(pathData) {
  let pathDataAbs = [];
  let offX = pathData[0].values[0];
  let offY = pathData[0].values[1];
  let lastX = offX;
  let lastY = offY;

  // analyze pathdata
  let commandTokens = pathData.map(com => {
    return com.type
  }).join('')
  let hasShorthands = /[hstv]/gi.test(commandTokens);


  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let typeAbs = type.toUpperCase();
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let isRelative = type === typeRel;
    let comPrev = i > 0 ? pathData[i - 1] : pathData[0];
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;

    if (isRelative) {
      com.type = typeAbs;

      switch (typeRel) {
        case "a":
          com.values = [
            values[0],
            values[1],
            values[2],
            values[3],
            values[4],
            values[5] + offX,
            values[6] + offY
          ];
          break;


        case "h":
        case "v":
          com.values = type === 'h' ? [values[0] + offX] : [values[0] + offY];
          break;


        case 'm':
        case 'l':
        case 't':
          com.values = [values[0] + offX, values[1] + offY]
          break;

        case "c":
          com.values = [
            values[0] + offX,
            values[1] + offY,
            values[2] + offX,
            values[3] + offY,
            values[4] + offX,
            values[5] + offY
          ];
          break;

        case "q":
        case "s":
          com.values = [
            values[0] + offX,
            values[1] + offY,
            values[2] + offX,
            values[3] + offY,
          ];
          break;
      }
    }
    // is absolute
    else {
      offX = 0;
      offY = 0;
    }

    /**
     * convert shorthands
     */
    if (hasShorthands) {
      let cp1X, cp1Y, cpN1X, cpN1Y, cp2X, cp2Y;
      if (com.type === 'H' || com.type === 'V') {
        com.values = com.type === 'H' ? [com.values[0], lastY] : [lastX, com.values[0]];
        com.type = 'L';
      } else if (com.type === 'T' || com.type === 'S') {

        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [cp2X, cp2Y] = valuesPrevL > 2 ? [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] : [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];

        // new control point
        cpN1X = com.type === 'T' ? lastX + (lastX - cp1X) : 2 * lastX - cp2X;
        cpN1Y = com.type === 'T' ? lastY + (lastY - cp1Y) : 2 * lastY - cp2Y;

        com.values = [cpN1X, cpN1Y, com.values].flat();
        com.type = com.type === 'T' ? 'Q' : 'C';
      }
    }

    // add command
    pathDataAbs.push(com)

    // update offsets
    lastX = valuesL > 1 ? values[valuesL - 2] + offX : (typeRel === 'h' ? values[0] + offX : lastX);
    lastY = valuesL > 1 ? values[valuesL - 1] + offY : (typeRel === 'v' ? values[0] + offY : lastY);
    offX = lastX;
    offY = lastY;
  });

  return pathDataAbs;
}


/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  return {
    x: (p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x,
    y: (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y
  };
}

/**
 * calculate single points on segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y: t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
}

function getPointAtQuadraticSegmentT(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  };
}



/**
 * based on @cuixiping;
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017100/calculate-center-of-svg-arc/12329083#12329083
 */
function svgArcToCenterParam(x1, y1, rx, ry, degree, fA, fS, x2, y2) {
  const radian = (ux, uy, vx, vy) => {
    let dot = ux * vx + uy * vy;
    let mod = Math.sqrt((ux * ux + uy * uy) * (vx * vx + vy * vy));
    let rad = Math.acos(dot / mod);
    if (ux * vy - uy * vx < 0) {
      rad = -rad;
    }
    return rad;
  };
  // degree to radian
  let phi = (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
  let cx, cy, startAngle, deltaAngle, endAngle;
  let PI = Math.PI;
  let PIx2 = PI * 2;
  if (rx < 0) {
    rx = -rx;
  }
  if (ry < 0) {
    ry = -ry;
  }
  if (rx == 0 || ry == 0) {
    // invalid arguments
    throw Error("rx and ry can not be 0");
  }
  let s_phi = Math.sin(phi);
  let c_phi = Math.cos(phi);
  let hd_x = (x1 - x2) / 2; // half diff of x
  let hd_y = (y1 - y2) / 2; // half diff of y
  let hs_x = (x1 + x2) / 2; // half sum of x
  let hs_y = (y1 + y2) / 2; // half sum of y
  // F6.5.1
  let x1_ = c_phi * hd_x + s_phi * hd_y;
  let y1_ = c_phi * hd_y - s_phi * hd_x;
  // F.6.6 Correction of out-of-range radii
  //   Step 3: Ensure radii are large enough
  let lambda = (x1_ * x1_) / (rx * rx) + (y1_ * y1_) / (ry * ry);
  if (lambda > 1) {
    rx = rx * Math.sqrt(lambda);
    ry = ry * Math.sqrt(lambda);
  }
  let rxry = rx * ry;
  let rxy1_ = rx * y1_;
  let ryx1_ = ry * x1_;
  let sum_of_sq = rxy1_ * rxy1_ + ryx1_ * ryx1_; // sum of square
  if (!sum_of_sq) {
    throw Error("start point can not be same as end point");
  }
  let coe = Math.sqrt(Math.abs((rxry * rxry - sum_of_sq) / sum_of_sq));
  if (fA == fS) {
    coe = -coe;
  }
  // F6.5.2
  let cx_ = (coe * rxy1_) / ry;
  let cy_ = (-coe * ryx1_) / rx;
  // F6.5.3
  cx = c_phi * cx_ - s_phi * cy_ + hs_x;
  cy = s_phi * cx_ + c_phi * cy_ + hs_y;
  let xcr1 = (x1_ - cx_) / rx;
  let xcr2 = (x1_ + cx_) / rx;
  let ycr1 = (y1_ - cy_) / ry;
  let ycr2 = (y1_ + cy_) / ry;
  // F6.5.5
  startAngle = radian(1.0, 0, xcr1, ycr1);
  // F6.5.6
  deltaAngle = radian(xcr1, ycr1, -xcr2, -ycr2);
  while (deltaAngle > PIx2) {
    deltaAngle -= PIx2;
  }
  while (deltaAngle < 0) {
    deltaAngle += PIx2;
  }
  if (fS == false || fS == 0) {
    deltaAngle -= PIx2;
  }
  endAngle = startAngle + deltaAngle;
  while (endAngle > PIx2) {
    endAngle -= PIx2;
  }
  while (endAngle < 0) {
    endAngle += PIx2;
  }
  let toDegFactor = 180 / PI;
  let outputObj = {
    pt: {
      x: cx,
      y: cy
    },
    rx: rx,
    ry: ry,
    startAngle_deg: startAngle * toDegFactor,
    startAngle: startAngle,
    deltaAngle_deg: deltaAngle * toDegFactor,
    deltaAngle: deltaAngle,
    endAngle_deg: endAngle * toDegFactor,
    endAngle: endAngle,
    clockwise: fS == true || fS == 1
  };
  return outputObj;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="400">
  <path id="path" d="M147.5 55.8c-5.8-7.2-13.6-14.4-25.5-14.4-8.4 0-15.4 8.2-27 8.2-9 0-13-7.8-23-7.8C51.4 41.8 31 60.4 31 84.5c0 12.8 4.2 32.5 13.6 49.7C51 146.7 59.4 155 69 155c6.7 0 14.7-6.3 24.2-6.3 8.4 0 16.2 5.6 23.8 5.6 18 0 35-23.5 35-39.3 0-.8-.3-1.4-.3-2v-1c-11.8-6.3-18.2-15.7-18.2-29.3 0-11 4.8-20.5 13.6-26.7l.5-.2zm-53-8.8c13.7-4.2 26.3-14.4 26.3-32 0-1.5-.2-3.3-.4-5.3l-.2-.8C106.4 12.6 94 23.4 94 40.3c0 1.6.2 3.6.6 5.8v.8z">
</svg>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    let d = path.getAttribute('d')
    let pathData = parseDtoPathData(d)

    // normalize to all absolute and longhands
    pathData = pathDataToLonghands(pathData)

    // calculate bounding box
    let bbPath = getPathBBox(pathData);

    // render bounding box
    let {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = bbPath;
    let rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect')
    rect.setAttribute('x', x)
    rect.setAttribute('y', y)
    rect.setAttribute('width', width)
    rect.setAttribute('height', height)
    rect.setAttribute('fill', 'none')
    rect.setAttribute('stroke', 'red')
    svg.append(rect)
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -6):

I know this is an old issue, but thought I would put this variant to Furtado's answer for reference here.

An easy way to get the bounding box for the path.

1. Make sure the path (or any other SVG element has an id on it.
2. Open the svg file in Chrome (or FF or probably IE).
3. Inspect the image
4. Open the console in the inspection tool.
5. Enter the JS:  document.getElementById("myPath").getBBox();  (where
       myPath is the id)

The bounding box info will be displayed in the console.

Same method, just no need for custom code.

Comment: What do you mean by custom code? How is that different from Gerardo's answer?

Comment: As I said It's not different just a variant of it.  His answer shows JavaScript code embedded with the svg image.  This does not work if the svg is used as an img tag as is most common.  So you have to create a custom page with this in it.

My version just lets you use the browser tools and a bit of js to find the same info.  Ergo, no custom code.