# Find rightmost/leftmost point of SVG path

Tags: svg, bounding-box, bezier

How to find leftmost/rightmost **point** of SVG C (bezier curve) path segment? I know there is `getBoundingClientRect()` and `getBBox()` but none of them apply since they return only single coordinate of the point.

---

Just to avoid XY problem - I want to split single path composed of bezier curves into several paths each monotonously going from left to right (or right to left). It means that on any single path should be no 2 points having equal X coordinate. I understand that required split point may potentially be *inside* the bounding box of a segment thus not being leftmost/rightmost, but I'm almost sure that way of finding such point should use same techniques as finding horizontally extreme point.

Comment: What do you mean `getBBpox(0` returns a "single point"? `getBBox()` returns the bounding box of the path. The leftmost point should be `bbox.x` and the rightmost should be `bbox.x + bbox.width`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: `getBBox` can let me know `x` coordinate of the target point, but not `y`. This is what I mean when say only single coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul LeBeau's comment and fancy animation on [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Higher-order_curves) inspired me for the solution. It is based mostly on following terms:

- Values of parameter `t` from `[0, 1]` can be matched to the curve
  points.
- For any parameter value point on the curve can be constructed
  step-by-step by linearly combining pairs of adjacent control points
  into intermediate control points of higher "depth". This operation
  can be repeated until only single point left - point on the curve
  itself.
- Coordinates of the intermediate points can be defined by
  `t`-polynoms of degree equal to point "depth". And coefficients of
  those polynoms ultimately depend only on coordinates of initial
  control points.
- Penultimate step of construction gives 2 points that define tangent
  to the curve at the final point, and coordinates of those points are
  controlled by quadratic polynom.
- Having direction of tangent in question as *vector* allows to
  construct quadratic equation against `t` where curve has required
  tangent.

So, in fact, finding required points can be performed in constant `O(1)` time:

```
  tangentPoints: function(tx, ty){
    var ends = this.getPolynoms(2);
    var tangent = [ends[1][0].subtractPoly(ends[0][0]),
                   ends[1][1].subtractPoly(ends[0][1])];
    var eq = tangent[0].multiplyScalar(ty).subtractPoly(tangent[1].multiplyScalar(tx));
    return solveQuadratic(...eq.values).filter(t => t >= 0 && t <= 1);
  }
```

Full code with assisting `Polynom` class and visual demo I placed into [this repo](https://github.com/blr-Oliver/bezier) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blr_Oliver/9Ld1m9vb/)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to iterate through the path length with `.getPointAtLength(i)` method, and then find the limits. Seemed like a fun thing to do so I made a quick and dirty implementation, this is the important part:

```
function findLimits(path) {

  var boundingPoints = {
    minX: {x: dimensions.width, y: dimensions.height},
    minY: {x: dimensions.width, y: dimensions.height},
    maxX: {x: 0, y: 0},
    maxY: {x: 0, y: 0}
  }
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
    var coords = path.getPointAtLength(p);
    if (coords.x < boundingPoints.minX.x) boundingPoints.minX = coords;
    if (coords.y < boundingPoints.minY.y) boundingPoints.minY = coords;
    if (coords.x > boundingPoints.maxX.x) boundingPoints.maxX = coords;
    if (coords.y > boundingPoints.maxY.y) boundingPoints.maxY = coords;
  }
  return boundingPoints
}
```

You can find the implementation here: https://jsfiddle.net/4gus3hks/1/

[image]

Comment: This has linear O(length) performance. Is there any way to do it faster, or maybe some routine out-of-the-box?

Comment: See this question for a mathematical solution instead of an iterative one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809978/calculating-the-bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier-curve